# Launch Gmail to send a mail coupled with an attachment

Tags: android, gmail

In my application, the user have the opportunity to export and import his data file, and i want to add also the option to send this data file by mail as attachment.
How can i do this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My code to send email with a image attachment:

```
public void sendViaEmail(String pAttachmentPath, String pSubjectLine) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, pSubjectLine);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
            "Screenshot ****************");
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile("file://" + pAttachmentPath));
    mActivity.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Or

```
public void sendViaEmail(File pAttachmentFile, String pSubjectLine) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, pSubjectLine);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
            "Screenshot ****************");
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pAttachmentFile));
    mActivity.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Comment: Is there any thing to add in the manifest? i'm getting a ForceClose.

Comment: @androniennn: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "ForceClose".

Comment: @Dongshengcn: the first `setType()` is unnecessary, since you call `setType()` again later. It also has the wrong MIME type (it would be `text/plain` instead of `plain/text`). Also, I recommend `Uri.fromFile()` rather than `Uri.parse()` and concatenation -- it is simpler and more reliable.

Comment: @CommonsWare: What could be the MIME type in my case? is it important to set it ? I have a file that has as extensions .dat .

Comment: @CommonsWare:`08-22 14:48:31.360: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(360): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-22 14:48:31.382: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(360): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND (has extras) }
`

Comment: @androidienn: "What could be the MIME type in my case?" -- how should I know? It is your data. "is it important to set it ?" -- yes, if you want your `Intent` to not have the exception you are seeing.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I mentionned that it's just a `.dat` file. Example: `Volkswagen-data.dat`. Any idea please?

Comment: @androidienn do you know the type of the file you are sending? .dat does not really tell us anything.