# Send an email with pictures attached via adb shell

Tags: android, email, shell, adb

I am doing the android test. And I need to know the way to use adb shell to run the test automatically. Does anyone know how to send an email with pictures attached via adb shell?
like this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:xxxx --es xxxxx
```

I would appreciate it if a complete example with subject and body is given.
I have tried the following command, but it does not work.

```
-e stream "file:///sdcard/test.jpg" -t image/jpeg
```

Comment: This a poorly designed test, because you are asking to test functionality that doesn't exist on a phone by default.  You would first have to write an android application that can send an email based entirely on an intent, without user interaction, then install it, and finally trigger it by sending an intent.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that the email app have no functionality to attach a mp3 file? How about attaching a picture? The main purpose of this test is to ensure that an email or a mms could be send out with files attached.

Comment: iirc you can "begin" an email with an intent, but the email won't be sent without further user interaction.  If you wish to do it automatically you have to write your own email sending program, at which point you are really testing your program and only by extension android.  The situation may be different for an MMS.

Comment: YES, you are right! "the email won't be sent without further user interaction". So after I send the command `am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:xxxx --es xxxxx` to the DUT, some keyevents are also needed to send the SMS out. But if files are needed to be attached, more keyevents are required. For different phones the procedures are different. However, use the shell command directly would reduce number of the procedures. So I wanted to know the way to attach files.

Comment: This might be a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148475/launch-gmail-to-send-a-mail-coupled-with-an-attachment only you will have to translate from the construction of an intent in code to the am command options.  It's been discovered that gmail often dislikes attachment paths that don't appear to be on the external storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The biggest difficulty for me lies in how to translate from the construction of an intent in code to the am command. I don't know the rules to be followed.

Comment: I have tried the following command, but it does not work.<br/>`-e stream "file:///sdcard/test.jpg" -t image/jpeg`

Answer (score -1):

If you have registered an email-account on your emulated device you can simply send an email to the address from anywhere (which basically means from any of your email accounts) - there is no need to use command line magic

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am doing the android test. So I need to know the way to use adb shell to run the test automatically.

Comment: This post does not answer the @Homer's question. He was asking to get it accomplished through the terminal.